# How can I get a list of all elements of a public inner enum?

Tags: java, enums, inner-classes

Given this class:

```
public class Outer {

  public enum Day {
      SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY
  }

}
```

I tried `new Outer().Day.values();` and `new Outer().Day.getEnumConstants();` but I'm getting `Day cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Any idea how I could access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access is as follows: `Outer.Day.values();` The enum `Day` is publicly accessible just like a static variable would be.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code using IDEONE and here is my solution (adapt it to your needs):

```
public enum Day {
      SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY
  }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Day[] d = Outer.Day.values();
        for (Day dd : d){
            System.out.println(dd);
        }
    }
```

The link is - http://ideone.com/B1qLKg

Is that what you wanted?